# How would I go about displaying HTML of a user-inputted URL using Google Apps Script?

Tags: html, google-apps-script, web-applications

I can't seem to get the HTML portion of the webapp and the `code.gs` portion to communicate with each other. Here is my code so far:

Code.gs:

```
function doGet() {
  //var url = Browser.inputBox('Enter URL', Browser.Buttons.OK);
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('search');
}

function sbox(url) {
  //var url = form.url;
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(response);
}
```

search.html:

```
<form>
  URL: 
  <input type="text" id="url" name="url" value=""><br>
  <input type="button" onClick="formSubmit()" value="Search1" />

  <script>
    function formSubmit() {
      var url = document.getElementById("url").value;
      google.script.run.sbox(url);
    }
  </script>

</form>
```

Comment: About ``displaying html`` you think, can you provide the detail information of the result you want?

Comment: @Tanaike I want to be able to display the html/website content of the url entered by the user in a search bar. Sharad Acharya has me on the right track, but now I'm getting "400 Invalid Request" errors from google.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I couldn't understand about what you want to do from your reply, yet. I apologize for my poor English skill.

Answer (score 0):

```
function formSubmit() {
    var url = document.getElementById("url").value;
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(closeIt).sbox(url);
}

function closeIt(){
    google.script.host.close()
};
```

However, instead of sending url to code.gs, you can just use `window.open(url, "_self");`
and open the window from the javascript as the apps script won't be able to do it.

Comment: Now when I use it, I get the 400 Bad Request error from google, and sometimes the page just goes blank. Here is my updated html: <form>
  URL: 
  <input type="text" id="url" name="url" value=""><br>
  <input type="button" onClick="formSubmit()" value="Search1" />

  <script>
    function formSubmit() {
    var url = document.getElementById("url").value;
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(closeIt).sbox(url);
    window.open(url, "_self");
}
function closeIt(){
google.script.host.close()

};
  </script>

</form>

Comment: Try removing `"_self"`